# How do I properly use an int to change text in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a text box where a character called "Dugo" tells the player something, but it isn't working. The script is supposed to change what the text says based on an int value. All of the buttons and text are connected up properly to the script and I changed it to a double but it still won't work. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DugoText1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public double text = 0;
    public GameObject DugoBox;
    public GameObject DugoText;

    public void ClickTheButton()
    {

        text += 1;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (text == 1) {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text1";
        }
        if (text == 2)
        {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text2";
        }
        if (text == 3)
        {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text3";
        }
        if (text == 4)
        {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text4";
        }
        if (text == 5)
        {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text5";
        }
        if (text == 6)
        {
            DugoText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "text6";
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us how update button get called when value get changed.

Comment: so DugoText is linked properly in the inspector and has a Text component on it? Its not on a child?

Comment: How is ClickTheButton run? Have you set up a [listener/event to the button](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) ? Also is the text a child of the player?

Comment: Everything is linked up properly. The text is a child of the button and they are hooked up by an empty called "Buttons." It contains all of the scripts for the buttons in the game, and all of them work but this one.

Comment: I would say that the most likely issue here is with ClickTheButton function, try putting a debug.log in the function to see if it is running or not.

Comment: You may want to store all the texts in a list or array then set the text in click method with list[text].

Answer (score 0):

I tested ur script and this is what I got - (click on these to see the image)

[Attach Dugo Script to a gameObject and attach said gameObject(not the script) to a Button's "On Click" event, drag the Text component to DugoScript gameObject's "Dugo Text" field under DugoScript1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvlHT.png)

[Run the game and press the button - text changes successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhkAk.png)

Comment: This is what I have done. For some reason it isn't working for me. I also see that you are using Unity 2020. I have Unity 2017. Would it maybe have something to do with that?